# Why does AlexNet use 96, 256 and 384 filters at Convolution layers?

Tags: python, image-processing, conv-neural-network

Here is a Python implementation of AlexNet.

```
    # 1st Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape= inputShape, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(4,4), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 4th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 5th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

# Passing it to a Fully Connected layer
model.add(Flatten())

# 1st Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(GetInputShape()[0] * GetInputShape()[1] * GetInputShape()[2],)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# Add Dropout to prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# 2nd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# 3rd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(1000))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(len(ClassNameList)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

At first Conv2d layer, it takes 96 as filter count
At the second Conv2d layer, it takes 256
At third 384 ...

I read many online books and reviewed many codes but still, I could not understand why did creator of AlexNet used these parameters. And how should I change them if I want to train AlexNet with images which are bigger than 227 x 227(input shape that accepted by trained AlexNet)?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I don't know neither why they made this choices of 96, 256, 384 filters. I think they try a lot a possibilities and find it was the best one.

To respond to your question of adapting the net to an image bigger of 227*227. My easiest solution will be to resize your image to that size so you can use the network on it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is my training takes about 10 hours. So after every resizing, I should wait 10 hours to see results

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. You want to learn new images with your net? If yes, learning take long time for such complex model for sure, but it doesn't depend of the size of the image in entry. Can you right me what the goal of what you're doing?

Comment: I have 500 x 500 input images and I want to modify AlexNet for my images. ( Since I have text images I cannot resize images to 227 x 227 )

Comment: OK! Try to change the inputShape of yout first layer to adapt it to your image 500x500 images